# Groovy GString in Sql.execute - text variables are not surrounded by ' and query fails

Tags: sql, groovy, gstring

I have the following problem, when I pass GString to SQL.executeInsert, the text variables are not automatically souranded by `'` so the insert query failes:

```
String value4fa = "I would like to get know"
int value4fb = 2
def query = "INSERT INTO TAB_A (F_A, F_B) VALUES (${value4fa}, ${value4fb})"
sql.executeInsert(query);
```

If I put `'` by myself:

```
 def query = "INSERT INTO TAB_A (F_A, F_B) VALUES ('${value4fa}', ${value4fb})"
```

Groovy informs me that I have introduced a security hole, because Groovy can not use PreparedStatement to execute the SQL query.

Could anybody explain me how to force Groovy to evaluate query body correctly and prepare the variables?

Comment: groovy should never need the ', because they are only required for literal strings (which should be avoided for several reasons), but not for bind variables

Comment: Is that the right syntax for your db? I'm more used to seeing INSERT INTO TAB_A (F_A, F_B) VALUES (${value4fa}, ${value4fb})

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have not tested this idea, but the code for 2.4.4 [is here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-sql/2.4.4/groovy/sql/Sql.java/?v=source).

The `execute(String sql, List<Object> params)` method uses prepared statements.

Given that, consider this example:

```
firstName = "yue"
lastName = "wu"
sql.execute("insert into people (firstName, lastName) "+
  " values (?,?)", [firstName, lastName])
```

If necessary, it is easy to add single-quotes to the variables themselves (rather than the SQL string).

Comment: I have removed the dead link to Codehaus and updated to point to source code for groovy.sql.Sql 2.4.4

Comment: if you have to manually add the single quotes it means the query is not being processed as a prepared statement. This could open you up to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 5):

You should not have to decorate strings with anything to have them converted to `PreparedStatement` automatically.

```
sql.execute("INSERT INTO TAB_A (F_A, F_B) VALUES ($value4fa, $value4fb)")
```

will do the correct thing for all the methods that accept a `GString` as a single parameter. *note the lack of `{}` which is syntactic sugar for `.toString()`*

The reason yours causes the complaint is that,

```
def query = "INSERT INTO TAB_A (F_A, F_B) VALUES (${value4fa}, ${value4fb})"
sql.execute(query)
```

is different than passing the `GString` directly to the method.

it applies the substitutions **before** passing `query` to the `.execute()` method. Given your example data, it passes the following to and the replacements have already happened. `"INSERT INTO TAB_A (F_A, F_B) VALUES (I would like to get know, 2)"` which is not even a valid SQL statement because the string value is missing the `'` around it.

This is functionally equivalent to using `String.format()`, `StringBuilder/Buffer.append()` or plain on concatenation using `+`.